# #pragma inside #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, microcontroller

I'm working in a micro-controller using the **C** language. In this specific micro, the interrupts have to be defined using `#pragma` in following way:

```
static void func();
#pragma INTERRUPT func <interrupt_address> <interrupt_category>
static void func() { /* function body */ }
```

The `<interrupt_address>` is address of the interrupt in vector table. The `<interrupt_category>` is either 1 or 2. For example, to define an interrupt in Port 0 pin 0:

```
static void _int_p00();
#pragma INTERRUPT _int_p00 0x10 1
static void _int_p00() { (*isr_p00)(); }
```

We define actual interrupt service routine elsewhere and use function pointer (like `isr_p00` in the example) to execute them.

It would be convenient if the interrupts could be defined using a macro. I want do define a macro in following way:

```
#define DECLARE_INTERRUPT(INT_NAME, INT_CAT) \
    static void _int_##INT_NAME(); \
    #pragma INTERRUPT _int_##INT_NAME INT_NAME##_ADDR INT_CAT \
    static void _int_##INT_NAME() { (*isr_##INT_NAME)(); }
```

The compiler throwing the following error:

```
Formal parameter missing after '#'
```

indicating following line:

```
static void _int_##INT_NAME() { (*isr_##INT_NAME)(); }
```

I guess preprocessor directives cannot be used in `#define`s? Is there any work around?

Comment: What microcontroller and compiler? If it's GCC based, there might be a special attribute macro yo can use, like in Microchip's C32: `void __ISR(_TIMER_5_VECTOR) SomeISR(void)`

Comment: The micro is OKI 431 and the compiler is from OKI: IDEU8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C99 has the new `_Pragma` keyword that lets you place `#pragma` inside macros. Basically it expects a string as an argument that corresponds to the text that you would have give to the `#pragma` directive.

If your compiler doesn't support this (gcc does) and you'd go for an external implementation of what you need (as said, `m4` could be a choice) the best would probably be to stay as close as possible to that not-so-new `_Pragma`. Then once your compiler builder catches up with the standard you could just stop using your script.

Comment: The compiler doesn't support _Pragma. :(

Comment: @Donotalo, too bad. it is only 11 years now that this standard exists ;-) You could try a mixed solution in just using `gcc` as a preprocessor and then using your native compiler for the subsequent stages of compilation.

Answer (score 1):

A workround is to use code generation or another macro language to preprocess your code.

ie write the code with a different extension.

Have your makefile or similar call the macro language (e.g. m4) or a script of some form to generate a .c file

Then compile that.

Comment: Looking for a solution that will not invoke other script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, what you are **specifically** asking is impossible. I'm presuming a preprocessor that works the same as the [GNU C Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). In the manual for that, [it states](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization):

> The compiler does not re-tokenize the preprocessor's output. Each preprocessing token becomes one compiler token.

Comment: I also thought it is impossible. But I'm wondering if any other way it can be achieved.